# SSRS How to show dynamic quantity of columns in Table?

Tags: xml, reporting-services, dataset, ssrs-2008, report

I have a xml datasource that returns me a xml like this:

```
<ArrayOfAttendanceStudentExchangeModel xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <AttendanceStudentExchangeModel>
        <Counter>1</Counter>
        <FatherLastName>Roque</FatherLastName>
        <MotherLastName>Parisaca</MotherLastName>
        <Names>Sergio Gustavo</Names>
        <Attendances>
            <string>P</string>
            <string>F</string>
            <string>F</string>
            <string>P</string>
            <string>P</string>
            <string>P</string>
            <string>P</string>
            <string>P</string>
        </Attendances>
    </AttendanceStudentExchangeModel>
</ArrayOfAttendanceStudentExchangeModel>
```

The web api method returns a Collection of some type as XMl.

```
public class AttendanceStudentExchangeModel
{
    public int Counter { get; set; }
    public string FatherLastName { get; set; }
    public string MotherLastName { get; set; }
    public string Names { get; set; }
    public string[] Attendances { get; set; }
}

[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage GetAttendanceSheet(string codigoDocente, int codigoHorario, int periodCode)
{
    {
        AttendanceSheetService attendanceSheetBuilder = new AttendanceSheetService();
        var attendanceSheetResult = attendanceSheetBuilder.GetAttendanceSheetCollection(codigoDocente, codigoHorario, periodCode);

        var content = new ObjectContent<List<AttendanceStudentExchangeModel>>(attendanceSheetResult, Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
        return new HttpResponseMessage()
        {
            Content = content
        };
    }
}
```

Query in Dataset:

```
<Query>
    <ElementPath>
        ArrayOfAttendanceStudentExchangeModel {} /AttendanceStudentExchangeModel
    </ElementPath>
</Query>
```

I define the Fields manually:

[image: Fields in DataSet]

And the Result:

[image: Result]

Result Desired:
[image: Result Desired]

The number of Attendances (Asistencias) can be different from one query to another.

How can I achieve this?